# For which pairs $(f,g) \in P \times P$ the polynomial $f * g$ is not reducible in $\mathbb (R, +, \cdot)$

Tags: polynomials

Let $P \subset \mathbb R[x]$ be defined as follows:

$$P = \{ax^3+bx+c \mid \ a,b,c \in \mathbb R\}$$

then let the operation $*$ be so defined on $P$:

$$(ax^3+bx+c)*(ux^3+tx+z) = aux^3+btx+cz$$

Then find out

- whether $(P,*)$ is a monoid and if that's the case determine its
  invertible elements;
- for which pairs $(f,g) \in P \times P$ the polynomial $f * g$ is not reducible in $\mathbb (R, +, \cdot)$.

The structure $(P,*)$ is a monoid if the operation $*$ is associative and if the struction has an identity element. So, let $f,g,h \in P$, $*$ is associative if

$$(f*g)*h = f*(g*h)$$

that is

\begin{equation}
\left((ax^3+bx+c)*(ux^3+tx+z)\right)*(wx^3+sx+k) =\\
(aux^3+btx+cz) * (wx^3+sx+k) = \\
(auwx^3+btsx+czk) = \\
(ax^3+bx+c) * (uwx^3+tsx+zk) = \\
(ax^3+bx+c) * \left( (ux^3+tx+z) * (wx^3+sx+k)\right)
\end{equation}

So $*$ is associative and since the identity element of the structure is the polynomial $x^3+x+1$, then $(P,*)$ is a monoid. The invertible elements of this structure are all the polynomials $ax^3+bx+c$ such that

$$(ax^3+bx+c) * (\alpha x^3 + \beta x + \gamma) = x^3+x+1$$

and that happens as

\begin{cases}
a \cdot \alpha = 1 \Leftrightarrow \alpha = a^{-1} \\
b \cdot \beta = 1 \Leftrightarrow \beta = b^{-1} \\
c \cdot \gamma = 1 \Leftrightarrow \gamma = c^{-1}
\end{cases}

and clearly there is no inverse for polynomials $f \in P$ such that $a = 0 \vee b = 0 \vee c = 0$.

I am struggling with the second request, I don't know how to find a polynomial $f*g$ so that it is irreducible in $(\mathbb R, +, \cdot)$. Any help, suggestion, push in the right direction is very welcome.

Comment: What does irreducible mean? What can you say about a polynominal that has roots (can it be irreducible)? And what can you say about polynominals of grade 3 in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and its roots?